# Parsing JSON Data from local server using JQuery.....but not getting result

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am Java Developer, but have a small task in Jquery. I have to get Json data parsed....
JSON data is as follows:

```
   [
   {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"},
   {"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Summer Salad","type":"veg"},
   {"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Black Beans Chicken","type":"non-veg"},
   {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Lentil Soup","type":"veg"},
   {"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Roasted Root Veg","type":"veg"},
   ]
```

And am Trying this code but I am not getting expected result......
I am trying to get the tags in div but no idea I am getting just..
.

> [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]

The code that I used is.............

```
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(result){
       $.each(result, function(i, field){
         $("div").append(field + " ");
       });
    });
```

Comment: when you are looping through the array and placing field, you are just placing the javascript object in the dom, that's why it is displaying [object Object]

Comment: each `field` is an object, you need to get it's properties, for example: `field.category`

Comment: The JSON is not valid. Remove the last `,` at `{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Roasted Root Veg","type":"veg"},
    ]` Otherwise as the guys wrote about the iteration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(result, function(i, field){
    $("div").append(field.category + " ");
});
```

Comment: I would go with a standard `for` loop since it faster but thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is an `Array of objects`.

`field` is the entire object in each iteration..

**field** `1st iteration` - `{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"}`

You would need to use a specific key to get the value

**field.category** which would give you **`Soups`** for the first iteration

```
.append(field.category + " ");
```

You have 3 keys in each object `category` , `menu_item` and `type`

So use the key on the object to access a specific value.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9Uyzy/)**